# set variables in an MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to learn about the Orchard MVC application. I see the following code but cannot understand what it is doing. Can someone explain what this:

```
User.As<UserPart>().Record.UserName = value;
```

means?

```
 public class UserEditViewModel  {
    [Required]
    public string UserName {
        get { return User.As<UserPart>().Record.UserName; }
        set { User.As<UserPart>().Record.UserName = value; }
    }

    [Required]
    public string Email {
        get { return User.As<UserPart>().Record.Email; }
        set { User.As<UserPart>().Record.Email = value; }
    }

    public IContent User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to read about generics.

Comment: Best way to learn MVC and new CMS apps is by placing a breakpoint in a good place in YOUR code, and looking at the callstack (or stacktrace), to understand the flow of control. And looking at the CMS source itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing the source, it looks like the call to `As<type>()` is equivalent to `obj as type`

i.e. the object is being cast as a type `type` -- `UserPart` in this case. So `User` is defined as `IContent` but in this case it is assumed that the class implementing that interface is of type `UserPart` and can be safely converted to that type.

So `User.As<UserPart>()` returns an object of type `UserPart` which presumably has a property `Record` on it.

It seems odd to me, because why abstract the `IContent` interface if you are tying the implementation to the type `UserPart`, but again, I don't know the code and it could well make sense in the greater context.

edit: I say tying the implementation, because presumably `User.As<UserPart>()` could return null if the underlying class is *not* of type `UserPart`, and there's no check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like this viewmodel is used to edit the currently logged in users details.

The 1st part of

`User.As<UserPart>().Record.UserName = value;`

is `User.As<UserPart>()` - and this looks to me like a C# object of Type `UserPart` is created by the static method call on the User class, and the object contains probably the logged in users details. I suspect it accesses the `HttpContext.Current`'s or `ControllerContext`'s Request property to know who is the current user and fetch his details. Once it has fetched the `UserPart` object representing the current logged in user `.Record.UserName = value` simply sets the incoming value on the object.

The `value` is an implicit argument in all set methods in C#.

The ViewModel's setters are usually called when binding a model during the Request's modelbinding just before actioninvoking. And the getters are called usually when rendering the view.

If you still find it difficult to understand  look at [Orchid Documentation](http://orchardproject.net/docs/) or at the [Source Code](http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1c3ba112913c) itself